# Modify Apache rewrite rule for Nginx

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

How to rewrite this Apache rewrite rule for Nginx?

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

I tried this but it doesn't work, I'm getting `HTTP 404` in `/var/log/nginx/access.log`

```
location @missing {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/index.php permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The nginx way to implement front controller pattern like in your question is:

```
location /api {
    try_files /index.php =404;
}
```